# How to fix 'missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' in estudy2 package R

Tags: r

I am working on my research which is based off event study. I downloaded the new `estudy2` package which is supposed to be made for event studies but when I try to run the code as per instructions on `cran.r`, I get a 'missing value where `TRUE/FALSE` needed'.

With all honesty, I am not an R expert (more of an R beginner) and alhough I tried to read some articles on similar problems, none seemed to be fitting to my issue.

```
#calculate rates of return from stock prices of companies
rates <- get_rates_from_prices(LUX,
                           quote = "Close",
                           multi_day = TRUE,
                           compounding = "continuous")

#calculate rates of return for one chosen market index
rates_indx <- get_rates_from_prices(prices_indx, 
                                quote = "Close",
                                multi_day = TRUE,
                                compounding = "continuous")

#calculate the expected rates of companies 
securities_returns <- apply_market_model(
  rates = rates,
  regressor = rates_indx$EU,
  same_regressor_for_all = TRUE,
  market_model = "sim",
  estimation_method = "ols",
  estimation_start = as.Date("2013-12-27"),
  estimation_end = as.Date("2014-03-10")
)
```

after the last part of the code, I get:

> Error in if (same_regressor_for_all && ncol(regressors) > 2) { :
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Can u show a small reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation `?apply_market_model`, the `regressor` argument should be "an object of the same class as `rates`". Looks like you are giving `rates` a data frame, and `regressor` just a vector.

Try with `regressor = rates_indx[, "EU", drop = FALSE]` to make sure it's a one column data frame, for which `ncol()` will give a valid result.